# How to format cells so they only accept numbers

Tags: excel-formula

How do I make a cell only accept numbers? I.e. you can't enter text, it will only allow numeric values to be entered based on the criteria of dropdown from another cell.

If A is BYB, then only numbers should be entered in B.
If A is with any other data, only text should be entered in B.

Comment: What you are looking for is data validation. You can there define what type of data a certain cell accepts.

Comment: True but need a formula based on dropdown list of another cell

Comment: Well the logical part is the one that is what you need to do yourself, SO is not a coding service; you need to show some effort in solving your own problems. There are multiple if not millions of ways to do what you are asking we to answer, what we need from you is unambiguous question that can be answered without doing a whole program for you.

Comment: Yes I got the result........=IF(AC2="BYB",(ISNUMBER(AD2)),IF(AC2="Insourcing",(ISTEXT(AD2))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use data validation custom formula on your cell

1. select your cell (ex cell B1 [selected] and constraint of type is on A1)
2. select *custom validation* in: main tab / data / data validation /data validation
3. enter formula: `=(type(B1)=A1)`

*type()* function return the value 1 for integer, 2 for string. So for number only, set A1 to 1.

Adapt the formula according your need (ex for same format as A1 `=(type(b1)=type(a1))`, ...)